# Invalid content was found starting element 'or' in mule-config.xml while using mule-restlet transport

Tags: restlet, mule

Firstly, please take a look at a snippet in `mule-config.xml`:

```
<model name="userModel">
        <service name="userService">
            <inbound>
                <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:63080"/>
            </inbound>
            <outbound>
                <filtering-router>
                    <outbound-endpoint address="vm://userController"/>
                    <or>
                        <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users/{userId}" verbs="GET"/>
                        <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users" verbs="POST"/>
                        <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users" verbs="PUT"/>
                        <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users/{userId}" verbs="DELETE"/>
                    </or>
                </filtering-router>
            </outbound>
        </service>
        <service name="userController">
            <inbound>
                <inbound-endpoint address="vm://userController"/>
            </inbound>
            <!-- TODO: How to implement UserController -->
            <component class="com.ggd543.mulerestletdemo.user.UserController"/>
        </service>
    </model>
```

When I deploy it to `$MULE_HOME/apps`, mule complain :
[image]

PS: My mule version is 3.1.2 and i am using `mule-transport-restlet-2.0.jar`

Is there any wrong in my `mule-config.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<or>` to `<or-filter>` will work. The doument (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/RESTLET/User%27s+Guide#User%27sGuide-URITemplateRouting) is too old. WTF